# FreeScale P2041RDB-PB Failed to boot

Tags: embedded, boot, powerpc

I cannot boot on P2041RDB-PB. All ethernet ports (5 ports) are blinking rapidly after I press poweron button.

I am trying to check on the serial using minicom, it doesn't have any output.

I am trying to boot from SD Card, it doesn't output anything at minicom, and I still got all ethernet ports blinking rapidly.

How should I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What the kind of bootloader did you used? please make it specific your question. Firstly, you can try to boot your P2041RDB PB using U-BOOT it's free don't forget to compile u-boot sourcecode for P2041 processor. You can use JTag Debugger to deploy uboot binary to your p2041rdb. You can read the help section in uboot homepage on how to make uboot call Linux OS or other Realtime OS like u/coss-ii.

Permios Amigossss

Answer (score 0):

My P1021 behaves the same, if I try to boot from MMC/SPI wihtout placing valid bootloader code. It is also not possible to connect via JTAG debugger because the processer is kept in reset.
I configure to boot from (NAND/NOR), then connect with JTAG debugger to flash uboot into SPI and then reconfigure the board to boot from SPI again.

This works for me.